# IntelliJ shows ": Unit " at the end of a method with return type 'Int'

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, methods

I am writing a program in Scala using the [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) IDE. And when I declare the return type of a method as `Int`, it shows an error and shows `: Unit` after the second bracket:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Zadanie3 extends App{
  def factorial(n:Int) : Unit = {
    @tailrec
    def gcd(a: Int, b:Int): Int = {

    } : Unit // Shows only in the IDE
  }
}
```

Why does it show `Unit` at the end of the method block and how can I fix it?

Comment: The IntelliJ IDE is just telling you that the _current state_ of `gcd()` is returning nothing (i.e. `Unit`) but the code says it's _supposed to_ return `Int`. Put something like `42` in  between those braces and the `Unit` warning will disappear.

Comment: jwvh, Nope, when i put ```println(x)```(or 42) in braces, Unit shows again

Comment: `println()` always returns a `Unit` not an `Int`. The IDE is telling the truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IDE is just trying to be helpful by showing current return type which is indeed `Unit` since you didn't provide any implementation yet. Simply finish the implementation of `gcd` and it will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE is warning of a bug in your code. If you compile this you get

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
    def gcd(a: Int, b:Int): Int = {
```

If you change the code to return an `Int` the IDE warning will go away.